# Is there an easy way to compare two files and error out if they are not identical?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, dll

As part of our Continuous Integration builds, I'd like the build to fail if a Visual Studio solution is using two different versions of the same dll.  We are using Jenkins for CI and MSBuild.exe to build our product.

I know that this can be accomplished via C# code, but I'm trying to avoid that.  I'd prefer to use something built into MSBuild or MSBuild Community Tasks or a built in command line executable like FC.exe.  I've looked at FC.exe and it outputs text that says

```
FC: no differences encountered
```

and I suppose I can direct the output to a file and then parse that file, but that seems hacky at best.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind...I just executed FC.exe within MSBuild and I noticed that it returns an error code of 1 when the files do not match.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke powershell via MSBuild (I think the community tasks have a cmdlet execution task) and leverage the Compare-Object cmdlet.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156812.aspx

Jenkins has a PowerShell module as well that you could use.